# Flutter json_serializable: fromJson returns null

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serializable

the json I receive from the api looks like this:

```json
{
  "USD": [
    {
      "name": "something",
      "value": 123
    },
    {
      "name": "something else",
      "value": 1234
    }
  ],
  "EUR": [
    ... same here
  ]
}
```

and my dart model looks like:

```dart
@JsonSerializable(anyMap: true, includeIfNull: true)
class StatisticsDto {
  StatisticsDto({this.statistics});

  final Map<String, List<StatisticsDetailDto>> statistics;

  factory StatisticsDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$StatisticsDtoFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StatisticsDtoToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class StatisticsDetailDto {
  StatisticsDetailDto({
    this.name,
    this.value,
  });

  final String name;
  final num value;

  factory StatisticsDetailDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$StatisticsDetailDtoFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StatisticsDetailDtoToJson(this);
}
```

I don't seem to be able to make it work, I get a 200 from the api, but the serialization returns null.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your  `statistics` value in the class  StatisticsDto should return `List<StatisticsDetailDto> statistics;` and if your values names then not match JSON key you need to add manually `@JsonKey(name: 'key)`. I recommend this extension which can convert JSON to json_serializable data https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hirantha.json-to-dart

Comment: Thank you will try that asap. One question, why should it be List<StatisticsDetailDto>? I reckon that would apply to responses that return a list like {[...]} but in this case the response is a map {"USD": [], "EUR": []} etc etc

Comment: Because you return StatisticsDetailDto as List. Returns Map matches the StatisticsDetailDto data.

Comment: Just tried your changes, it still returns null unfortunately. The property 'statistics' from StatisticsDto is supposed to return a map of <String, List<StatisticsDetailDto>>, each String key has a value which is a List<StatisticsDetailDto>. I have been scavanging SO and the documentation for hours but could not find anything about this particular use case

Comment: Added a example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your `JSON` objects should look like converted to Dart data class with `json_serializable`

```json
{
    "USD": [{
            "name": "something",
            "value": 123
        },
        {
            "name": "something else",
            "value": 1234
        }
    ],
    "EUR": [{
            "name": "something",
            "value": 123
        },
        {
            "name": "something else",
            "value": 1234
        }
    ]
}
```

Dart data class with `json_serializable` without `Map` support:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'statistic_dto.g.dart';
part 'currency.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class StatisticDto {
  StatisticDto({this.usd, this.eur});

  @JsonKey(name: 'USD')
  List<Currency>? usd;
  @JsonKey(name: 'EUR')
  List<Currency>? eur;

  factory StatisticDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _$StatisticDtoFromJson(json);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StatisticDtoToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Currency {
  Currency({this.name, this.value});

  String? name;
  int? value;

  factory Currency.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CurrencyFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CurrencyToJson(this);
}
```

Run:

```sh
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

In your first example, your Map statistics have no key that why it always returns null. JSON file would look like this for your first class Data

```
// For: final Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> statistics;
{
    "statistics": {
        "USD": {
            "name": "One",
            "value": 1
        },
        "EUR": {
            "name": "Four",
            "value": 4
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this indeed works with a fixed list of currency codes. However, is there any way to achieve the same with a dynamic response e.g. { "USD": [], "EUR": [], "AUD": [], ... }?

Comment: I don't know where you from taking this `JSON` file but your main `Map` statistics have no key and that's why is always `null`, and you can't return it as Map. `Map<[Key not exist in the JSON file], List<StatisticsDetailDto>> statistics`

Comment: Explained in the my example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to serialize a json with fixed keys, please refer to Arnas' answer.

In my case, the json has dynamic keys, e.g. it's a map with an indefinite number of keys (corresponding to a currency code in my case), and a corresponding value (an array of objects).

Now, I reckon @JsonSerializable is not suitable for this kind of scenario, hence I implemented my own .fromJson() factories.

```dart
class StatisticsDto {
  StatisticsDto({this.statistics});

  final Map<String, List<StatisticsDetailDto>> statistics;

  factory StatisticsDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      StatisticsDto(
          statistics: json.map((String currency, dynamic details) {
              final List<StatisticsDetailDto> currencyDetails = details
                .map<StatisticsDetailDto>(
                    (detail) => StatisticsDetailDto.fromJson(detail))
                .toList();
            return MapEntry<String, List<StatisticsDetailDto>>(currency, currencyDetails);
          })
      );
}

class StatisticsDetailDto {
  StatisticsDetailDto({
    this.name,
    this.value,
  });

  final String name;
  final num value;

  factory StatisticsDetailDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      StatisticsDetailDto(
          type: json['name'],
          value: json['value'],
      );
}
```